# (Cocoa error 1570.), "NSValidationErrorKey" error

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, mkmapview, nsmanagedobject

My app should be deleting NSManagedObjects called "Pin" that contain the following properties:

```
@NSManaged public var imageData: NSData?
@NSManaged public var imageURL: String?
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var pin: Pin?
```

...however, I am getting the error:

```
"NSLocalizedDescription": The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), "NSValidationErrorKey": imageData]
```

The imageData property is set as an optional, so I'm a bit confused as to why Core Data is failing to delete.

Here is the didSelect function that executes the deletion:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    if !isEditing {
        do {
            let pinAnnotation = view.annotation as! PinAnnotation
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Pin")
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude == %@ AND longitude == %@", argumentArray: [pinAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, pinAnnotation.coordinate.longitude])
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            let pins = try CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Pin]
            selectedPin = pins![0]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("failed to get pin by object id")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "collectionViewSegue", sender: self)
    } else {
        mapView.removeAnnotation(view.annotation!)
        if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
            CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context.delete(selectedPin)
        }
        CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()
        return
    }
}
```

My pin class:

```
    convenience init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Pin", in: context) {
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    } else {
        fatalError("Unable to find entity name")
    }
}
```

Pin properties extensions:

```
extension Pin {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Pin> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Pin>(entityName: "Pin")
}

@NSManaged public var latitude: Double
@NSManaged public var longitude: Double
@NSManaged public var images: NSSet?
```

}

...and instantiation of the Pin NSManagedObject:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state != .began { return }
    print("Tap gesture recognized")

    // Create the annotation
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let newCoordinate = self.mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom:self.mapView)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate

    // Initialize NSManagedObject 'Pin' with properties
    selectedPin = Pin(context: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context)
    selectedPin?.latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude
    selectedPin?.longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude

    if let selectedPin = selectedPin {
        let pinAnnotation = PinAnnotation(objectID: selectedPin.objectID, title: nil, subtitle: nil, coordinate: annotation.coordinate)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pinAnnotation)

        FlickrClient.sharedInstance().getImagesFromFlickr(pin: selectedPin, context: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context, page: 1) { (images, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print("There was an error get images objects")
                return
            }

            if let images = images {
                for image in images {
                    image.pin = selectedPin
                }
                performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                    self.images = images
                    CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print("The context has changes: \(CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().context.hasChanges)")
    CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()

}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: did you try putting a breakpoint at the delete line and checking to see if the selectedPin has the imageData filled

Comment: @AjayReddy I did do that. In fact, I reset all content and settings to make sure I wiped out all the existing data first. For the first pin I tap when in edit mode to delete, it works fine. However, the contents of selectedPin on my attempt to delete a second pin are -via print statement: (<Pin: 0x6080006904a0> (entity: Pin; id: 0xd000000000240000 <x-coredata://EAF2DE4E-26BD-4445-9F84-7CB422505641/Pin/p9> ; data: <fault>)

Comment: @AjayReddy any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the data inside your "Pin" is not being filled properly....when you are instantiating the object "Pin" with values.....can you make sure that you are filling all the variables inside "Pin"...you can check this in the init() method of your "Pin" Class

Comment: I have edited the post to show how I instantiate the NSManagedObject "Pin", as well as it's class and extension. In trying to make this work, I also received a separate error that is likely related: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'pin' between objects in different contexts". My NSManagedObjectContext is shared instance, so I'm not sure how this occurs. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by eliminating one instance of my saving function:

```
CoreDataStack.sharedInstance().saveContext()
```

at the bottom of my handleLongPress function. This was being called prior to assigning images to the local variable in my view controller. The saveContext() only needed to be called within performUIUpdatesOnMain (my GCD async method) function.

This code in that same class was also unnecessary:

```
for image in images {
                image.pin = selectedPin
            }
```